# Python (3.7.4), requests: for loop getting only the last item

Tags: python, python-requests

I have this code:

```
links = ['https://google.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://amazon.com']
for url in links:
    r = requests.get(url)
    r.text
    result = r.text
    
print(result)
```

But this will get only the last item of the list (amazon.com).

So how do I get all the requests into one?

tia

Comment: Put your `print` statement inside the loop (or build up a list).

Comment: You can create a list and append the results, simplest way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are re-assigning the result without storing it anywhere.

You need to store them in for example a list:

```
result_list = []

for url in links:
    r = requests.get(url)
    r.text
    result = r.text
    result_list.append(result)

print(result_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

try it this way:

```
links = ['https://google.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://amazon.com']
for url in links:
    r = requests.get(url)
    result = r.text
    print(result) # this is the primary issue. the print statement isn't in the loop
```

Comment: `//` is not how you comment in python. Please change to `#` so they can actually execute the code.

Comment: my bad, been doing a lot of javascript lately. **blush **